# Yii php form submit

Tags: php, forms, yii

```html
<form class='form-horizontal' action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('item/default /submit'); ?>" type="post">    
    <div class='control-group'>
        <label class='control-label'><b>Title : </b></label>
        <div class='controls'>
            <input type='text' name='cat_title' class='cat_title' />    
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='control-group'>
        <label class='control-label'><b>Image url : </b></label>
        <div class='controls'>
            <input type='text' name='image_url' class='image_url' />    
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class='control-group'>
        <label class='control-label'></label>
        <div class='controls'>
            <button type='submit'  class='btn btn-info'>Save</button>   
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

When the submit button is pressed, Yii takes me to index.php instead of the url defined in form action.
The form action url is correct.
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: not sure if this is your problem, but are you aware that creating a form like this, instead of using CActiveForm or CHtml::beginForm, will mean that no CSRF will be generated? Therefore unless you specify in your config file that the item/default/submit is not to use CSRF you will get an error. I am not sure why it would redirect to your home screen but maybe you have code elsewhere doing that. If you already know this then sorry for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in the URL, so replace this...

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('item/default /submit');
//                                 ^ - here is the space
```

...with this...

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('item/default/submit');
```

**EDITED:** as noted by @Cookie_J5, have a look into using the "Yii-way" of building forms: [Creating Form](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.view)

Comment: thanx bro. but removing space hasn't solve the problem

Comment: ok, what do you have in the controller for that action / view? it may also be something you set in your config/main - urlManager, if you're using it, maybe there is a route redirecting `item/default/submit` to the main page...

Comment: ...or, for that matter, what is the content of `item/default/submit`? do you see anything in the logs...?

Comment: In the controller, there is just an echo statement. And urlManager is commented out.  I even tried with different other function names. But it's not working out.

Comment: i found this line in the log. Can you suggest how to stop it ?.......CWebApplication->run()
REQUEST_URI=/b2b/index.php?r=item/default/submit

Comment: what's the error on that line, doesn't the log say?... by the way, have a look at the below answer of @AndreyMischenko, maybe it's the answer...

Comment: sry. i mistook, log has no error. but the solution given below is not working for me.

Comment: what happens if you replace `action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('item/default/submit'); ?>"` with `action="item/default/submit"`?

Comment: so? what's the lesson? fix your url and you'll find the answer to your question...

Comment: by the way, how do you plan using `webserver/index.php?r=item/default/submit`? this url will not redirect you to that page but will rather just set value of `r` index of `$_GET`, meaning `$_GET['r']` would equal `item/default/submit`, that's it... in plain PHP, you could then use `$_GET['r']` but only on the same page you have the form on... i'm pretty sure it's not what you want, by the way...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('item/default/submit');
```

with

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('/item/default/submit');
```

Comment: when i click submit button, the form goes to webserver/index.php file instead of webserver/index.php?r=item/default/submit.

Comment: dude, it will be something with your url rules, i'm almost 100% sure, there is otherwise no reason for this redirection... have you tried echoing the url? try this somewhere in a view file: `<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('item/default/submit'); ?>` - what do you get printed on your page?

Comment: when  <?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('item/default/submit'); ?> is used as a link it works fine. But why is it not working when it's used in action of form ?

Comment: is there any default form action path defined in yii ?...i am a complete noob dude.....:(

Comment: like someone else said in a comment, try using one of Yii's built-in form methods...

Answer (score 0):

To use Yii::app()->createUrl() you have to set proper path in a UrlMananger in protected/config/main.php file. As for me you can just set form action manualy. For example, set it to `/item/default/submit/`